# ¿Significado de return None?

Tags: python, array

Cuando en un bucle de python ponemos `"return None"`, ¿cuál es realmente el significado de esto?

Comment: Tu pregunta se entiende mejor si la ilustras con una función (corta, en formato texto) donde hayas visto tal patrón. Usa la opción 'Editar' para agregar la información

Comment: Pues que la función está retornando el valor `None`. Es un valor especial que quien lo reciba puede chequear mirando algo como `if resultado is None`, para tomar la decisión que corresponda. Típicamente suele usarse en funciones que deberían retornar un resultado, pero por lo que sea el resultado no se puede calcular o encontra. Por cierto que poner `return None` es equivalente a poner `return` a secas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En python, todas las funciones devuelven un valor. Si no devuelve un valor explícito, entonces se considera que devuelve `None`.

Con `None` se estaría diciendo que no devuelve nada, lo que en otros lenguajes se consideraría un *procedimiento* o *procedure*. Como en el *tipado gradual* se necesita anotar el tipo de dato devuelto, es frecuente ver ahora explícitamente que se está devolviendo `None` cuando no hay ningún valor de retorno:

```py
def saludo() -> None:
    print("Hola")
```

Es equivalente a:

```py
def saludo() -> None:
    print("Hola")
    return None
```

Literamente, devolver `None` es como si devolviera algo vacío. No hay que confundirlo con que no **retorna nada**. Una función que no retorna sería una que da error o que se queda enganchada en un bucle infinito, que no sigue el camino de salida que tiene previsto. En python se indica con la anotación `typing.NoReturn`:

```py
from typing import NoReturn

def stop() -> NoReturn:
    raise RuntimeError('no way')
```